# Script (python, applescript, bash) to automaticlly convert a set of pyramidal tiled image INTO a set of large tiffs using ndpi2tiff?

Tags: python, bash, applescript

I feel like this should be a really simple solution, but I still can't seem to get it to work.

I have several hundred (more coming!) large pyramidal tiled images of histopathology cases created a hammamatsu scanner that outputs images in the NDPI format, aka whole slide imaging (WSI). There's already a tool called ndpi2tiff in a package called NdpiTools, that does the hard part. It will analyze a ndpi file (XYZ.ndpi) and create a new tiff file (XYZ.tif). Unfortunately, you can't use the *.ndpi wildcard argument and just batch convert all the files. It would be impractical to convert them one by one. I messed around with applescript (on a Mac, but have python installed) and only got errors where either no input was being directed to the ndpi2tiff OR it would try to act on the directory/folder and not the files within.

Usage is: ndpi2tiff -options [image2convert.ndpi]

Located in /usr/local/bin

https://www.imnc.in2p3.fr/pagesperso/deroulers/software/ndpitools/

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find` and `-exec` on the command line (bash):

```
find . -name '*.ndpi' -exec ndpi2tiff -options {} \;
```

You can use whatever options you like (replace `-options`).

Answer (score 0):

A Bash `for` loop will also do the job:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /PATH/TO/YOUR/IMAGES

for filename in `ls *.ndpi`; do
    ndpi2tiff "$filename"
done
```

Not the most intuitive language, but it has its uses.